# Automatically redirect email with new FROM/TO fields

Tags: email, sendmail, outlook-2010, procmail

I receive emails from a sub-contractor. I need to automatically resend the content of these emails to a distribution list from my company email address. We currently use Outlook Exchange as our main mail server but I am willing (actually prefer) to use Linux to parse/redirect. I am not too concerned about scrubbing headers, just updating the FROM/SENDER and TO/RECIPIENT fields. There may also be attachments which need to be carried along.

I have seen a similar post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/50941/how-can-i-automatically-forward-an-e-mail-and-change-sender) on SuperUser which references 'procmail' in one of the answers but is vague.

My best approach so far would be to set up a mail client on Linux to pull in the Outlook traffic then parse with procmail and resend. Has anyone seen examples of this? Have a better idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how Procmail works.  Procmail is an autonomous agent which typically runs on your mail server and processes each incoming message as it arrives.

The forwarding functionality you request isn't part of Procmail proper, but the Procmail distribution comes with a utility `formail` which can rewrite headers for you.

Given a message on standard input, it can replace the "From:" and "To:" headers with new values like this:

```
formail -I"From: Important Account <corporation@example.com>" \
 -I"To: Little Peon <person@example.org>" -ICc:
```

(The empty `-ICc:` makes sure to zap any `Cc:` header if there is one.  You might also want to zap old `Received:` headers.)

The output can then be piped to e.g. `sendmail -oi -t` to submit it back into the mail stream.

Of course, this is also easy to put in a Procmail recipe if you want it to happen automatically when email arrives.  This is really run of the mill Procmail processing so you should be able to find plenty of examples, including within the Procmail manual.  But here's the long and the short of it;

```
:0c
* regex which matches the messages you want to forward
| formail -I"From: account@example.com" -I"To: person@example.org" -ICc: \
  | $SENDMAIL $SENDMAILFLAGS -t
```

Remove the `c` flag if you don't want to receive the original in your inbox.  Remove the condition if you want to forward all mail unconditionally.

Comment: Thanks, tripleee. I'm not an admin, so the piece I am missing is the interaction between the exchange server and linux mail server. How do these integrate? Or must they be independent?

Comment: Without more information about your email topology, there is no straightforward way to answer that. If you receive these messages on your Linux server, all you should need is a `.procmailrc` in your home directory. If not, maybe you need to explain the relationship between the two mail servers, perhaps in a separate question, perhaps on a different site (https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ depending in whether you need general help or specifically server networking help).

Comment: If you have IMAP access to your Exchange inbox, maybe forget about Procmail, and do it with a simple custom IMAP client. If you insist on Procmail, I'll point to https://github.com/tripleee/procimap but it's probably much too much for this simple problem, especially if you are new to Procmail.

Comment: Right on. I think I have enough ammo to move forward. Gracias.